# Can't delete marker from map (Cannot read property 'unselectAll')

Tags: drupal-7, openlayers-3

I'm trying to delete a marker from a map but I'm not able. I'm able to select it, to move it but when I try to delete it it doesn't do anything.

When I click the delete option the following js error pops up:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unselectAll' of undefined openlayers_behavior_geofield.js?n5kot1:39
controls.push.OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.handleKeypress openlayers_behavior_geofield.js?n5kot1:39
OpenLayers.Handler.OpenLayers.Class.callback OpenLayers.js?n5kot1:205
OpenLayers.Handler.Keyboard.OpenLayers.Class.handleKeyEvent OpenLayers.js?n5kot1:647
(anonymous function) OpenLayers.js?n5kot1:63
```

Any one has any idea of why is this happening?

I'm using Openlayers 7.x-2.0-beta9 and Geofield 7.x-2.1

Thanks!

Geofield file that is failing (openlayers_behavior_geofield.js):

```
if (options.allow_edit && options.allow_edit !== 0) {
    // add an Edit feature
    controls.push(new OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature(layer, {
        deleteCodes: [46, 68, 100],
        handleKeypress: function(evt) {
            if (this.feature && OpenLayers.Util.indexOf(this.deleteCodes, evt.keyCode) > -1) {
                // We must unselect the feature before we delete it
                var feature_to_delete = this.feature;
                this.selectControl.unselectAll();
                this.layer.removeFeatures([feature_to_delete]);
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: can you post the code you are using the delete the marker?

Comment: also, creating a jsfiddle or including a link to a website that demonstrates the problem would help too.

Comment: I have not done any modification to the original code. I have updated the question with the code!

Comment: And the page that has the problem is not online yet... But what I'm doing is to create a Drupal content with a map and to draw the locations on the map. When editing the Drupal content for deleting the location in the map, is when I cannot delete the marker.